# Python-Бот телеграм с бд, ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, база-данных, telebot, бот, telegram

Сначала код работал стабильно, потом когда начал вставлять данный в бд из кода, начались проблемы.
Вот код:

```
import pymysql
import telebot
import time
from config import host, user, password, db_name
from telebot import types, apihelper


bot = telebot.TeleBot(токен)


try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print('Connect')
except Exception as ex:
    print('Not connected')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    regbtn = types.KeyboardButton('Зарегистрироваться')
    markup.add(regbtn)
    bot.send_message(user_id, "Привет! Я - бот бухгалтер. Для начала тебе надо 
    зарегистрироваться. Нажми на кнопку ниже, чтобы это сделать", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def registration(message):
    word1 = message.from_user.first_name
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if message.text == 'Зарегистрироваться':
        num = 0
        temp = bot.send_message(user_id, 'Введи свой начальный капитал(в рублях, целым числом)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(temp, num)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            info1 = "INSERT info (name, date) VALUES (%s, NOW())"
            cursor.execute(info1, word1)
            values1 = "INSERT records (value, operation) VALUES (%s, 1)"
            cursor.execute(values1, num)
            connection.commit()


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

если убрать эту часть кода:

```
values1 = "INSERT records (value, operation) VALUES (%s, 1)"
            cursor.execute(values1, num)
            connection.commit()
```

и все её компоненты, бот спокойно работает(конечно, с чего бы ему не работать. Он в таком случае ничего и не делает)

В общем, помогите плиз, не знаю как это пофиксить

Трасса ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyProgects/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "D:\PyProgects\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 637, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "D:\PyProgects\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 699, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "D:\PyProgects\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 659, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "D:\PyProgects\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 130, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "D:\PyProgects\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 82, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос трассу ошибки, непонятно ведь где именно ошибка :) Хотя кое-что есть... в `cursor.execute` вы используете binding-параметры, это хорошо, но параметры туда передавайте не как есть, а оборачивая в кортеж/список, пример: `cursor.execute(info1, (word1,))` (кортеж), `cursor.execute(info1, [word1])` (список)

Comment: %s поменять на %i видимо нужно, т.к. вызываешь для num

Comment: NMD, в таком случае выдает следующую ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyProgects/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)                                                                                                      [между этим еще куча кода ошибки, который не вмещается, если надо могу отправить]
TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 0
^^^^^^^
temp = bot.send_message(user_id, 'Введи свой начальный капитал(в рублях, целым числом)')
bot.register_next_step_handler(temp, num)
                                     ^^^
```

Второй параметр, передаваемый в `register_next_step_handler` - это функция, которую нужно выполнять следующей. А вы ей число `num` передаёте, поэтому такая ошибка выходит.

Comment: И как это исправить? Прости, я немного деревянный, до меня не дошло, как это сделать. UPD: все, понял. Щас попробую исправить

Comment: @Матвей Написать функцию, которую бот должен выполнять после. Прописать её вторым параметром. Я на самом деле в ботах не силён, но причину ошибки могу найти вот )